# How to use multi-input logic gates in Chisel3?

Tags: verilog, hdl, chisel

I am implementing a Carry Lookahead Adder using Chisel3. In order to shorten  latency, I need to use multi-input logic gate.

However, even if I write code like

```
io.out:= a | b | c | d | e
```

, the generated verilog code will be like

```
assign _T = a | b
assign _T_1 = _T | c
assign _T_2 = _T_1 | d
assign io_out = _T_2 | e
```

which uses 4 OR gates, and leads to 4x gate delay.

I am wondering that is there a way to generate multi-input logic gates?
Such as

```
assign io_out = a | b | c | d | e
```

or

```
or (io_out, a, b, c, d,e)
```

Answer (score 0):

One work around would be to construct a multi input OR gate class where you can define how you want the connections to be made so that the translations happen the way you want.